# seems I can't do anything inside addOnCompleteListener or new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshop>

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check how many products in my database are for sale. I haveto retrieve data from database, save it on an ArrayList, then check if each of the element in the ArrayList is for sale. To do so, I have a isPromozione() function which returns true or false, whether it is or not for sale.

I'm including the code I think is not working. Please ask if you need anything else.

I'm pretty sure the problem is here because I've already used all my custom methods somewhere else and they work fine

```java
private void checkPromotions(){

    FirebaseFirestore db=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    mDb = db.collection("Prodotti");


    final ArrayList<Prodotti> prodottiArrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    mDb.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

            for(DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                prodottiArrayList.add(document.toObject(Prodotti.class));
            }


            for(Prodotti prodotto : prodottiArrayList){
                if (prodotto.isPromozione()){
                    promotionQty++;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

promotionQty is an int declared globally as 0 and never used anywhere else, mDb is also declared globally and is a CollectionReference. I expect promotionQty to be 5 since in the db I only have 5 product for sale, but the actual output is 0.

EDIT: ok I checked out by putting promotionQty++ here and there in the code, and it doesn't do anything in onComplete at all. I'll assume it never goes there, but why's this happening? how can I fix it?

EDIT2: it seems it doesn't access to my Prodotti from the db. I tried to access to any other collection in it. now I have no clue of what to do.

Comment: get() is asynchronous and returns immediately.  If you check the value of prodottiArrayList before the callback is fully complete, then the array will appear to be empty.

Comment: so what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Only use the array after the callback in complete and the array is entirely populated.

Comment: sorry I don't get it, isn't everything already in the onComplete method?